# arabic letters turns ?? in excel using java

Tags: java, string, file, stringbuilder, outputstream

I am creating an excel file and 
I have data in String builder which is a mix of arabic and english and 
when i print in console it is displaying correctly but when I write it to file arabic letters are turned to unknown characters

below is my code

```
System.out.println("Arabic Stream1--"+sb.toString());//I can see arabic  text in console 
System.out.println("Default Charset"+Charset.defaultCharset().name());//UTF-8
outputStream.write(sb.toString().getBytes());
```

Any help on this Please.Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

This is about Excel and fonts, not about Java. The font you chose in Excel is not able to display the character. Use a font that does.

Comment: Ø§Ù„Ù…Ø³Ù…Ù‰ Ø§Ù„ÙˆØ¸ÙŠÙÙŠ this is what i get using the above code

Comment: But when i try using default tool option(oracle Adf) of excel creation it is displaying fine,Only due to my customization where i create excel in java it is causing the issue

Comment: How do you even create an Excel file in Java using a StringBuilder?

Comment: I followed as said in the below link http://vikaspogu.blogspot.com/2016/09/adf-export-to-excel-programmatically.html

Comment: That is not an Excel file, that is a tab-separated file, that Excel happens to know how to open.

Comment: What happens if you set the content type to what it really is: a text file, save that to disk and open that file with Excel.

Comment: I tried the text file also arabic characters is changed to unknown junk values

Comment: There's two issues here: 1) what is the encoding (What do the bytes mean? Is it UTF-8 where there are 1, 2 or 3 bytes for a single character, or is the output ASCII, with only 1 byte, or some other encoding?) and 2) does the application that you use to view the file know what encoding it is supposed to use (What to do with these bytes?)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add to your JVM arguments when launching:

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

just to make sure it will force your entire app have UTF-8 encoding.